# Backing up of the "Mail flow - Rules" in the "Exchange admin center"

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I need to take a backup of the "Mail flow - Rules" in the "Exchange admin center"

```html
$TransCollect = Export-TransportRuleCollection
$TransCollect1 = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($TransCollect.FileData)
$TransCollect1  | Set-Content -path c:\temp\2.xml
```

But I cannot extract anything from the XML file because at the start of the XML file is a special character.
So If run ....
[XML]$AppConfig = Get-Content –Path "c:\temp\2.xml"
I get several errors.
Is there is a problem in the "[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString" line itself OR 
how do I remove this special character.
See the screenshot for the special character. It shows up at the beginning of the file"
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use this and bypass the special character entirely as well as getting the EXCHANGE RULES into a extractable format.

```html
$File_Collect = "c:\temp\1.xml"
$TransCollect = Export-TransportRuleCollection
Set-Content -Path $File_Collect -Value $TransCollect.FileData -Encoding Byte
[XML]$TransXMLCollect = Get-Content –Path $File_Collect
$TransXMLCollect.SelectNodes("//rule") | % { $_.InnerText }
```

Answer (score 0):

The "special character" you see is the [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for Unicode (aka UTF-16LE) (`\xFF\xFE`) because you used `[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString()`. To read that file with Get-Content, you need to specify that same encoding using its `-Encoding` parameter:

```
[XML]$AppConfig = Get-Content -Path "c:\temp\2.xml" -Encoding Unicode
```

Depending on the PowerShell version you are using, Get-Content by default uses different encodings:

- Versions 5.1 and below use the encoding that corresponds to the system's active code page (usually ANSI)
- Versions 6 and up use UTF8NoBOM

<sup>Is there a specific reason for writing the XML in UTF16 ? Usually, UTF-8 is used with XML</sup>

Comment: Get-Content –Path "c:\temp\2.xml" -Encoding Unicode -- does not work. It throws a bunch of errors. My objective as mentioned in the Title of the post is to extract the "Mail flow - Rules" in the "Exchange admin center. Is there a different way of doing it let me know

Comment: @hdsouza Then please edit your question and explain some more what is is you want to achieve **and** show us the errors you get there too (in full). I cannot see your screen, so there is no way for me to say what the _bunch of errors_ mean..

Comment: @hdsouza One thing I noticed (and fixed) was that the hyphen for the `-Path` parameter was not a hyphen at all, but a so-called [M dash](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html). This could explain the error(s)